# Running a PowerShell script on a remote machine doesn't work in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run a Powershell script on a remote machine via ssh. I have configured Azure release but I am getting a very strange error.

This is how my config file looks like

```
steps:
- task: SSH@0
  displayName: 'Run shell script on remote machine'
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: 'Dev SSH service'
    failOnStdErr: false
    runOptions: script
    scriptPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Pipelines/Scenarios/test.ps1'
    readyTimeout: '20000'
```

This is what my Powershell script looks like:

```
Write-Host "Hello, World!"
```

The remote computer is configured with ssh via PowerShell.

I am getting the error as shown in the picture

[image]

Transcription:

```
tr -d '\015' <./test.ps1> ./test.ps1._unix

##[error]At line:1 char:14

##[error]+ tr -d '\015' <./test.ps1> ./test.ps1._unix

##[error]The '<' operator is reserved for future use.

##[error]    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException

##[error]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported

##[error]Error: Command tr -d '\015' <./test.ps1> ./test.ps1._unix exited with code 1.
```

Comment: It's looking like the remote host runs a Bash (or maybe `sh`) script which attempts to translate the line endings from Windows CRLF to Unix LF-only conventions. Only the admin of that system can really tell you what's going on, though perhaps this is something Microsoft does. (It would not be surprising, other than in that usually they would force you to use Windows when you don't want to, rather than the opposite.)

Comment: I am using windows server.

Comment: This is the scenario that works.
 - task: SSH@0
   inputs:
    sshEndpoint: 'Dev SSH service'
    runOptions: 'commands'
    commands: 'Write-Host "Hello, World!"
    failOnStdErr: false
    readyTimeout: '20000'

Comment: I am vaguely guessing `script` means shell script and `commands` means Powershell, but I am only inferring from what you are reporting here; I have no familiarity with Azure.

Comment: @tripleee 
Is it possible to specify in yaml that I intend to use a ps script?
Here is a link to the documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops)

Comment: That's some (predictably) atrocious documentation. Let's just say it doesn't manage to refute my conjecture above.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I have created a System.Debug variable. I saw how SSH0 works, in the end I just copy the script to the remote machine and execute it by setting Run = commands.

```
- task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
  displayName: 'Copy scripts to on remote machine'
  inputs:
     sshEndpoint: 'Dev SSH service'
     sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Pipelines\Scenarios'
     contents: '**.ps1' 
     targetFolder:  'C:\Test\Scenarios'
     cleanTargetFolder: false
     overwrite: true
     failOnEmptySource: false
     flattenFolders: true

 - task: SSH@0
   inputs:
   sshEndpoint: 'Dev SSH service'
   runOptions: 'commands'
   commands: 'C:\Test\Scenarios\test.ps1'
   readyTimeout: '20000'
```

Comment: Since you have a workaround, you could [mark your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) to improve this ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I just came across this same issue and thought I would post the fix that worked for me.

I am using a PowerShell script and I have configured my windows target machine to default the SSH shell to be PowerShell.

The error above comes from the script trying to remove windows line endings here:
[link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/d432af9864d41b9520e12158709418f69dc111a4/Tasks/SshV0/ssh2helpers.ts#L219) (Line 219)

To fix this issue:

RunOptions should be changed from "Inline" to "Comands"
The inline node should become commands

From:

```
- task: SSH@0
    inputs:
        sshEndpoint: YOUR_SSH_ENDPOINT_HERE
      runOptions: inline
      inline: | 
        Write-Output 'Hello, World!'
    displayName: Hello world
```

To:

```
- task: SSH@0
    inputs:
        sshEndpoint: YOUR_SSH_ENDPOINT_HERE
      runOptions: commands #<- changed this
      commands: | #<- changed this
        Write-Output 'Hello, World!'
    displayName: Hello world
```

Edit: This will break with multi line statements that need to share variables. Trying to use the ssh task for a batch/powershell target will create a headache, `PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3` or even just a powershell task + `New-PSSession -ComputerName xxx` is the best way around this.